# Kubernetes Dashboard not accesible

Tags: kubernetes, calico

[image]
[image]

Now when I try to access the url https://172.21.97.117:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy I could see the title loaded but not few js associated with it. below are the javascript I got from browser's devtools

[image]
I could access the kubernetes dashboard container directly from the machine where is it deployed(worker 1) and the js as well but from master and other worker node the js is not loading.

[image]
Dashboard is installed from - https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Since you can access it directly on the container, this might solve:

There is a  [known issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52729)  related to Kubernetes 1.7.6 where  `/ui`  redirect does not work.
Try to add trailing slash at the end of  `/proxy/`  redirect url: https://172.21.97.117:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Let me know if that helped.